# Bash script: 'locale' was unexpected at this time

Tags: node.js, bash, powershell, git-bash, package.json

I'm trying to run the following script, but I am getting an error saying 
`'locale' was unexpected at this time` . I'm on a Windows machine, running this in Git Bash. It's a `package.json` file.

```
{ 
...

"build-lang": "for locale in en-US ar-EG es-ES; do echo Building ${locale}; 
ng build --configuration local-$locale; done",

...    
}
```

`'locale' was unexpected at this time`

This is inside a nodejs package.json file and I'm executing the script in the following way:
`npm run build-lang`

Comment: are you running the code in a powershell console? it doesn't seem likely that PoSh is involved ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i tried both powershell and git bash. same error

Comment: that does not look like a powershell error message. i would remove the powershell tag unless you are _sure_ that it has something to do with the problem. [*grin*]